# Getting error javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: android

I am facing a problem while calling api from android application . Api create no problems when i call them from browser . I am posting my code below and the response i got.

```
    HttpResponse httpresponse=null;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity entity=null;                                 
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parList,"UTF-8"));
        httpresponse= client.execute(post);
        entity=httpresponse.getEntity();
        response=EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        Log.d("code of response", ""+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        if(httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
            if (httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {


                Log.d("code", ""+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

                Header authHeader = httpresponse.getFirstHeader(AUTH.WWW_AUTH);
                DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();

                //Parse realm, nonce sent by server. 
                digestScheme.processChallenge(authHeader);

                UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("cuztomise", "123456");
                post.addHeader(digestScheme.authenticate(creds, post));

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient2.execute(post, responseHandler);
                return responseBody;
            }
            return response;
            }else{

                makelogs(url, "", parList.toString(),""+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),context_new,response);
                return response;
            }
    } catch (IOException | MalformedChallengeException | AuthenticationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        makelogs(url, e.toString(), parList.toString(),""+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),context_new,response);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        makelogs(url, e.toString(), parList.toString(),""+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),context_new,response);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
```

Error i got is  javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Comment: May this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https

Answer (score 0):

> this is due to the connection
>   established with the client machine is
>   not secure.

It is due to the fact that you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. Probably you didn't use the correct port number for HTTPS.